# Azure AD B2C errors during reset password at the first logon (using custom policies)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, change-password, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to force password reset after the first logon (in Azure ADB2C) using the Custom Policies as explained in [the "reset password" repo](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon/readme.md).

I'm using the custom policies, and a validation error accours while I'm trying to upload the "SignUpOrSignin.xml" custom policy. The message is:

> A required Metadata item with key "ApplicationObjectId" was not found
> in the TechnicalProfile with id
> "AAD-UserRemoveMustResetPasswordUsingObjectId" in policy
> "B2C_1A_signup_signin" of tenant "resetpasswordtest.onmicrosoft.com"

These are the steps I followed:

1. I downloaded the custom policies XMLs file from [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts) GitHub example (as stated at the end of the [readme.md file](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon/readme.md#community-help-and-support))
2. I "substituted" the "yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com" and "facebook client"
3. I "merged" the "SignUpOrSignin.xml" and "TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml" with the ones taken from [the "reset password" repo](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon/readme.md).
4. I created the "mustResetPassword" extension attribute (using the Azure portal)
5. I created one user using the graph utilies (in that why I'm 100% sure that the user has been created in a safe way with the proper "mustResetPassword" extension attribute)
6. Finally I uploaded the following xmls into the portal (in order):

> TrustFrameworkBase.xml
>
> TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml
>
> PasswordReset.xml
>
> ProfileEdit.xml
>
> SignUpOrSignin.xml

The problem occur when I try to upload the last one (SignUpOrSignin.xml)
What is wrong here? [Here](https://artinessstoragetest.z6.web.core.windows.net/Adb2cResetPasswordCustomPolicies.zip) you can find the full implementation of the previous 5 xml files.

Please take a look to the following section where I pasted the "TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml" and "SignUpOrSignin.xml" custom policies.

Thanks for reading

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" 
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="resetpasswordtest.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://resetpasswordtest.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions">
  
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>resetpasswordtest.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsSchema>
    <!--Demo: Specifies whether user must reset the password-->
    <ClaimType Id="extension_mustResetPassword">
        <DisplayName>Must reset password</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Specifies whether user must reset the password</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
  </ClaimsSchema>
  </BuildingBlocks>

  <ClaimsProviders>
   <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>  

        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <OutputClaims>
            <!--Demo: Read the 'must reset password' extension attribute -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mustResetPassword" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserRemoveMustResetPasswordUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">DeleteClaims</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mustResetPassword" />            
          </PersistedClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <!--Demo: to create the extension attribute extension_mustResetPassword, you should upload the policy 
            and create one account. Then ***comment out this technical profile***.
            -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mustResetPassword" DefaultValue="true" />
          </PersistedClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <!-- Facebook claims provider -->
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
          <Metadata>
            <!--Demo action required: Change to your Facebook App Id-->
            <Item Key="client_id">313412440187068</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email public_profile</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>


    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">44444444-2222-2222-2222-555555555555</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">44444444-2222-2222-2222-555555555555</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="44444444-2222-2222-2222-555555555555" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="44444444-2222-2222-2222-555555555555" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

  </ClaimsProviders>

  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInWithForcePasswordReset">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
      
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
           <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
           <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!--Demo: check if change password is required. If yes, ask the user to reset the password-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>extension_mustResetPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>            
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>extension_mustResetPassword</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>            
          </Preconditions>        
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
          <!--Demo: check if change password is required. If yes remove the value of the extension attribute. 
              So, on the next time user dons' t need to update the password-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>extension_mustResetPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>            
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>extension_mustResetPassword</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>            
          </Preconditions>        
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserRemoveMustResetPasswordUsingObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserRemoveMustResetPasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
 
        <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
 
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>

</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
  TenantId="resetpasswordtest.onmicrosoft.com"
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_signup_signin"
  PublicPolicyUri="http://resetpasswordtest.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>resetpasswordtest.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignInWithForcePasswordReset" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed out configuring the policy for extension attribute support.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#azure-ad-b2c-extensions-app

This entire process can be automated with my tool: https://aka.ms/iefsetup before starting to use the samples.

Comment: Thank you Jas Suri, it's working now! As you guessed, the reason of the bad behaviour was related to the lack of "extension attribute" in the "ClaimsProvider". May I ask you a favor? Can you edit your comment [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/197#issuecomment-804444460) and change "SocialAndLocalWithMFA" to "SocialAndLocalAccounts". It was really difficult for me to start from the "MFA" example because there were many (useless) line of code to handle. Other people should face the same problems.

Comment: We always recommend using the MFA sample, you do not need to modify the starter pack to achieve any goal. All samples *connect* to the starter pack.