# How to track failed login attempts in Azure AD B2C Custom Policy?

Tags: passwords, azure-ad-b2c, custom-attributes, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, login-attempts

I am trying to track a User's failed login attempts and save it into the B2C's users by their  ObjectId, which I can retrieve by their sign in name. The policy I am using is the regular signupsignin policy from Microsoft's page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#custom-policy-starter-pack

I have already created a custom attribute for the B2C user called failedLoginAttempt and saved as an int. In my TrustFrameworkExtension.xml, I have created a ClaimType called extension_failedLoginAttempt.

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_failedLoginAttempt">
    <DisplayName>count failed logins</DisplayName>
    <DataType>int</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

What I wanted to try to do next was to grab this attribute from the user via their sign in name and then increment it by 1 each time they failed to login. But the issue I am having is tracking where in the XML files (Extesions, localization and base) on where that is happening, but I am not able to find it.

I do see technical profiles like the below where they get called during a user's sign in, but there doesnt seem to be any information on username or password validations when I dig into the details of those profiles:

`<IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" /> <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />`

My end goal is to force the user to change their passwords after a certain number of failed attempts, similar to the question from this post: [Custom Policy for Force Reset password on first login not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65337221/custom-policy-for-force-reset-password-on-first-login-not-working?rq=2)

But I don't want to do it after one failed attempt but after multiple attempts and then I forced the user to change their password.

Comment: did you find out how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What I did find out was that Azure has its own built in Security for credential attacks that forces password resets. It limits my control for what I need but that was the closest I could get for now:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management